# Formatting Request Header Values

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

Trying to figure out if I need to escape characters in my header value.  Much like the example belowif I'm sending a header authorization over for OAuth to a server resource:

```
“PUT /api/v1/articles/6.json HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: /\r\nUser-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.5\r\nContent-Length: 9\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\”nMu4u9pLRfDrxhPVK5yn\“, oauth_nonce=\”5346IG1e5bV3ytQwdFqkP8Rgr0VJiA9Xb4FE0\“, oauth_signature=\”64545G%2Byp%2F2BsqJ%2BUUgbjIIIV9E%3D\“, oauth_signature_method=\”HMAC-SHA1\“, oauth_timestamp=\”1330022891\“, oauth_token=\”ivouGxpsJbyIU5viPKOO\“, oauth_version=\”1.0\“\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: someHostNameHere\r\n\r\n”
```

Right now I'm sending it (the value portion for my Authorization collection) over as one big string like this for my value for the authorization key:

```
"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=Mu4u9pLRfDrxhPVK5y, oauth_nonce=5346IG1e5bV3ytQwdFqkP8Rgr0VJiA9Xb4FE0, oauth_signature=64545G%2Byp%2F2BsqJ%2BUUgbjIIIV9E%3D, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_timestamp=1330022891, oauth_token=ivouGxpsJbyIU5viPKOO, oauth_version=1.0"
```

Comment: There are many [open source .Net libraries](http://oauth.net/code/) for oAuth. Why don't you use one of them?

Comment: this is my own code.  The first string you see is an example request I got from the API I'm gonna be consuming...from their support staff.  So I wasn't sure if this escaping is universal or what.  Why don't I use an open source OAuth framework?  a) cause I already rolled m my own and b) cause I don't like bloat or unexpected changes or have to be pushed a certain direction and c) this stuff after you get it, isn't that hard to roll your own.  The simple the better, and mine is extensible but I don't need an entire bloated framework to give me basic OAuth functionality that we need here

Comment: so back to my question.  Is escaping characters like this in a request header universal in that I am missing them and should have them in mine?

Comment: Unless  you don't use TcpClient/Socket, you never have to send such a string.

Comment: Please elaborate on what your tech stack is, seems like raw sockets so far.  Is this c#?  Their example uses form encoded params. Typically you add an Authorization header with your OAuth params the way you have them.

Comment: Yes C#.  Ok, maybe mine is not form encoded?  I specified that as the content type though.

Comment: "Unless you don't use TcpClient/Socket, you never have to send such a string" can you elaborate?  what do you mean such a string, you mean escaped chars like the escaped quotes and such?

Comment: The quickest way to determine whether you are doing it right is if it works or not.  When you submit the data, does the other side give you an expected response?  If yes, then you are good.  Otherwise post what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it:

```
var url = "https://somedomain.com/resource/v1/";
var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
var oAuthHeader = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=Mu4u9pLRfDrxhPVK5y, oauth_nonce=5346IG1e5bV3ytQwdFqkP8Rgr0VJiA9Xb4FE0, oauth_signature=64545G%2Byp%2F2BsqJ%2BUUgbjIIIV9E%3D, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_timestamp=1330022891, oauth_token=ivouGxpsJbyIU5viPKOO, oauth_version=1.0";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Not sure why you would want to construct your own raw HttpRequest.  Obviously you would call some function to generate your OAuth header values, this is demonstrative only.

Comment: that's exactly how I did do it.  Thanks.  So you add it literally as a big long comma dilimeted string...just wanted to verify I was doing that right as for the value of the Authorization when trying to add oauth params to the header's auth.

Comment: only other thing...shouldn't the url include the resource you're trying to get?  I guess you have it in the middle but when I had /api/ that's literal text that's not gonna change.  The resource for this third party API I'm creating a wrapper for would be e.g. Customers.json after the v1/